# Determine flux using Gauss's theorem

Tags: vector-analysis

Here's the task I'm a bit confused with:

> Find using Gauss's theorem the outward flux seen from the point $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ of the vector field $$\mathbf{v}=\left(\begin{matrix}x^2yz\\xy^2z\\z\end{matrix}\right)$$
>   through the area $M$ defined by
>   $$M:=\left\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=z,\;0\leq z \leq 1\right\}$$

I don't understand the meaning of the "*seen from the point*". Does it influence somehow the solution?

Here's how I do this.

At first I find divergence of $\mathbf{v}$:
$$\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{v})=2xyz+2xyz+1=4xyz+1$$
To find the volume integral I make the following transformations:
$$-1\leq x\leq 1\\ -\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}\\0\leq z \leq 1$$

Applying divergence theorem we obtain
$$\int_{\partial V}\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n}\operatorname{do}=\int_V\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{v})d\mu=\int_{-1}^1dx\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy\int_{0}^14xyz+1dz\\=\dots\\=\pi$$

I skipped the routine calculation of the volume integral which I've done on the paper.

Does it seem to be correct? Is there anything to be done with this additional "*seen from the point*" condition?

Comment: Are you sure of your integration boundaries ? Especially for example on $z$, which satisfies : $0 \leq z \leq 1$... Another question is whether or not you should take into account the flux at the top of your *cone*, corresponding to the surface $\{(x,y,1), x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1\}$. This is definitely not clear, is it ?

Comment: @jibe The boundaries of $z$ were incorrect, thank you, I've edited the question. I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean, that an imaginary observer that stands at the point $(0,0,1)$ will only see the flux that is going through the base of the cone? And having this in mind we would need so subtract the flux through the curved surface of the cone from the flux through the whole cone?

Comment: A surface has two side, the "seen from a point" part determine which side should be considered as outside. Depend on which point you pick, the resulting flux can differ by a minus sign. Of course, stated in this way, it is still not clear which side the question is referring to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your boundaries of integration are incorrect.
The domain ${M = \{(x,y,z) \,|\, x^{2} + y^{2} = z , 0 \leq z \leq 1 \}}$ corresponds qualitatively to the surface of a *cone* of height $1$ oriented along the $z-axis$, without its top-hat. Indeed, one should note that the *top* of this cone, which corresponds to the surface $\{(x,y,1) \,|\, x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \}$ does not belong to the domain $M$.

If we want to determine the flux of the vector field $\boldsymbol{v}$ through the surface $M$ using Gauss's Theorem one may proceed as follows

$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_{\rm M} \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, d S & = \int_{\partial \rm Cone}  \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, d S - \int_{\rm Top} \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, d S 
\\
& = \int_{\rm Cone} \text{div} (\boldsymbol{v}) \, d V - \int_{\rm Top} \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, d S \, ,
\end{aligned}$$

where $\int_{M} d S$ corresponds to the outgoing flux through the surface $M$, $\int_{\partial \rm Cone} d S $ corresponds to the flux through the surface of the *entire* cone with its top, and $\int_{\rm Top} d S$ corresponds to the flux through the *top* of the cone.

The integration $\int_{\partial \rm Cone} d S$ can be estimated thanks to Gauss's Theorem as follows. The domain of integration is given by

$$\begin{cases}
0 \leq z \leq 1 \, ,
\\
-\sqrt{z} \leq x \leq \sqrt{z} \, ,
\\
- \sqrt{z - x^{2}} \leq y \leq \sqrt{z - x^{2}} \, .
\end{cases} $$

(The boundaries are different than yours, since you are integrating on the entire cylinder) so that it becomes

$$ \begin{aligned} 
\int_{\rm Cone} \text{div} (\boldsymbol{v}) \, d V & = \int_{0}^{1} d z \int_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}} dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{z - x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{z - x^{2}}} d y \, (4 x y z + 1) 
\\
& = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}$$

On the other hand, the flux through the top $\int_{\rm Top} d S$ is given by

$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_{\rm Top} \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, d S & = \int_{-1}^{1} d x \, \int_{- \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d y \, \, (x^{2} y \,,\, x y^{2} \,,\, 1) \cdot (0,0,1) 
\\
& = \int_{-1}^{1} d x \, \int_{- \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d y \, 1
\\
& = \pi
\end{aligned} $$
(Note the fact that on the top, the outgoing normal is  given by $(0,0,+1)$)

As a conclusion, we obtain that $\int_{M} \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \, dS = - \frac{\pi }{2}$

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. By the way you could use polar coordinates when determining the flux through the top, that is easier

Comment: @DmitryKazakov Glad to help! For the flux on the top, the shortest way is to note that $\boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} = 1 = cst.$, so that $\int_{\rm Top} ... d S = \text{Surface}(\text{Top}) \times 1 = \pi$, since we all know the surface of a disk of radius 1 ! ;)

Comment: I have one question: why do you write that the top surface doesn't belong to the domain $M$?

Comment: @DmitryKazakov Only looking at the definition of your domain $M$, you can see that for $z = 1$, only the points $(x,y)$ such that $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ belong to M. It corresponds to a circle of radius in the plane $z=1$. To have a *closed* surface $M$, M should have been defined as $M = \{ (x,y,z) \,|\, x^{2} + y^{2} = z , 0 \leq z \leq 1\} \cup \{ (x,y,z) \,|\, x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 , z = 1\}$. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Indeed, now it's clear, thank you

Comment: Why do you have $-\sqrt{z^2-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{z^2-x^2}$ and not $$-\sqrt{z-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{z-x^2}$$

So there should stay $z$ instead of $z^2$, should't it?

Comment: @DmitryKazakov You're definitely right. I got mixed-up with the notations. I edited my answer accordingly. Note that the boundaries for $x$ are also changed, since it becomes $- \sqrt{z} \leq x \leq \sqrt{x}$. The final result is also modified, since we now obtain $- \pi / 2$.